# How to prevent the contents of a div from beaking its parents dimensions in ie6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

I've got a two column layout like this:

```
<div>

<div id='left'></div>
<div id='right'></div>

</div>
```

When the contents of the left div are that of a flash object with dimensions that exceed the left column's width, the right column no longer floats to the right properly in ie6. It falls underneath the left div.  All other browsers (of course) are fine.

Comment: Can you provide the basic structure?  Otherwise we have to guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the css property

overflow:hidden

will solve this problem. It will just not show any image, text, ect that goes outside the div.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like `overflow: hidden`?